# SQL order by clause customized

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run a query that fetches me all the names that have for say "ana" in it but i want the result like this

1. Anna
2. Brianna

not like

1. Brianna
2. Anna

which means the name starting with "an" should come first and then anything containing "an" in them

My SQL query is like this but this dpes not give me the desired results. I checked some other stuff but not quite sure how to use and does not give the desired results.

```html
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE  Name LIKE 'ana%'
AND Name LIKE '%ana%'
```

Comment: use `order by` in the query to get the desired ordering.

Comment: why not  .. order by Name asc

Comment: you mean 'Ana' and 'Briana'? Your result would be an empty set...

Comment: no i mean first i want the results for name starting with an and then any names containing an in between or in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the records only once and then order them and according to your requirements i understand that you need to order something like this by using ORDER BY CASE

```html
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE  Name LIKE '%ana%'
    ORDER BY CASE
 WHEN Name LIKE 'an%' THEN 1
 WHEN Name LIKE '%an%' THEN 2 
 ELSE 3
 END
```